# What does this line of code in Rust mean?

Tags: rust, methods

I was going through rust-by-practice and came across a problem. I have no idea what a particular line of code does. This is the exact piece of code for context:

```
fn example1() {
    // `T: Trait` is the commonly used way.
    // `T: Fn(u32) -> u32` specifies that we can only pass a closure to `T`.
    struct Cacher<T: Fn(u32) -> u32> {
        calculation: T,
        value: Option<u32>,
    }

    impl<T: Fn(u32) -> u32> Cacher<T> {
        fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T> {
            Cacher {
                calculation,
                value: None,
            }
        }

        fn value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
            match self.value {
                Some(v) => v,
                None => {
                    let v = (self.calculation)(arg); // This exact line of code
                    self.value = Some(v);
                    v
                },
            }
        }
    }

    let mut cacher = Cacher::new(|x| x+1);
    assert_eq!(cacher.value(10), __);
    assert_eq!(cacher.value(15), __);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `calculation` field of `Cacher` is a closure (type `T` where `T: Fn(u32) -> u32`), and that line is calling it with `arg` as an argument, then assigning the resulting `u32` to `v`. Without the parentheses, `let v = self.calculation(arg)` will look for a method named `calculation`, which doesn't exist. The parenthesis force a different order of operations which produces a different result.